# Looping Through a (CSV) in Bash as variables

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, csv, while-loop

I'm trying to use a CSV file with 3 column (Name,Date,Manager) and run a script that will read the CSV and use its variables to send an email for every row

The test columns looks like this

```
Name    Date .        Manager
user1   11/11/2018    test1
user2   11/12/2018    test2
user3   11/13/2018    test3
```

What I have so far is this

```
    while IFS="," read Name Date Manager
    do
        echo $Name, $Date $Manager
    sendEmail -o tls=yes -f YourEmail@gmail.com -t $Manager@domain.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu my@gmail.com -xp YOURPASSWORD -u "Hello $Name" -m "How are you? Testing $Date."
    done < test.csv
```

`echo $Name, $Date $Manager` only prints out the first row of the column.
output `user1   11/11/2018    test` which I will think only send one email instead of 3

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Well, you don't show a .csv for input, so I suspect you are happy with your parsing. There is nothing wrong with `while read stuff; do more stuff; done < test.csv` That would read line by line. Remove (comment out) the `sendEmail` line and see if you `echo` your values correctly first -- report back.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read Name Date Manager
do
    echo $Name, $Date $Manager
done < test.csv`

Gives me
`Name, Date Manager
user 11/11/2018/ test1`

Comment: Sorry -- post your input file (with the commas) so I can look at your parsing.

Comment: The first row in the csv yes but not sure how to echo the the other two rows as variables in the loop

Comment: Your doing it in a loop, it should echo each set of variables as they are read. Do you have DOS line ends in your input file? (highly suspected)

Comment: Input file is `INPUT=/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv` not sure if that what you mean

Comment: Are you using WSL where you got your data file from the Windows side? Do `hexdump -Cv filename.csv` and look at the line ends. If you see `0xd 0xa` that is *Carriage Return* then *Line Feed*, which is the DOS *CRLF* line ending that will screw up your read. Run the file through `dos2unix`.

Comment: i dont, 

the entire script without the sendmail line is

`#!/bin/bash

INPUT=/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv
while IFS="," read Name Date Manager
do
    echo $Name, $Date $Manager
done < /Users/user/Desktop/test.csv`

Comment: I'm on macos is that helps

Comment: Yes, yes, but `test.csv` can either use *Unix Line Endings* (`'\n'`) or DOS line ending (`'\r\n'`). It will matter to bash. If you have it, do `dos2unix test.csv testnew.csv` and try reading `testnew.csv`.

Comment: Great, using '\n' gave the output of each row with `echo $Name, $Date $Manager`

Comment: Now you have a new bit of knowledge of what to check for in your data files `:)`

Comment: Yes deff. Can the `echo` be replaced with another command and it will loop with those variables while reading it from the CSV?

Comment: Yes, you can put any number of valid commands inside your `while` loop between `while; do` and `done` and you can use `$Name, $Date $Manage` as many times as you like.

Comment: This all worked perfectly, thanks